# Elementor created Header is not updating on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I've used the Elementor Header and Footer plugin and created a header with Elementor. I am able to see the header on my admin page but the website does not update. The only header I am able to see is that from the default theme of Wordpress. Please assist.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This would be really hard for us to help you with, since there is no code. It could be a theme issue, cache issue - really anything.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.